# Join two dataframes based on distance between latitude-longitude pairs

Tags: pandas, left-join, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I have two dataframes that contain latitude-longitude pairs.
One example of a dataframe can be:

```
latitude = [40.7128, 37.7749, 34.0522]
longitude = [-74.0060, -122.4194, -118.2437]
index = [1, 2, 3]
df = pd.DataFrame({'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': longitude, 'index': index})
```

while the second dataframe could be

```
latitude = [40.7324, 37.7569, 34.0612]
longitude = [-74.0070, -122.4284, -118.2507]
index = [1, 2, 3]
df = pd.DataFrame({'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': longitude, 'index': index})
```

I want to end up with one dataframe that then has 6 columns (index, latitude, longitude, latitude_x, longitude_x, distance) containing the lat-lon values of the first dataframe with joined lat_x-lon_x and their distance BUT ONLY if the lat-lon pairs of the two dataframes are not further apart than e.g. 50m. Both dataframes have approx. 250000 rows. How can I do this?

Comment: Kindly add expected output dataframe

Comment: what do you want to do in the case in which multiple points are within 50 metres of the same point? Or are we assuming that will never happen

Comment: In that case I would chose the closest one. As @MarkHill says, the cross-join would make the dataframe exceptionally large. I haven't used geopandas much, but ideal would geospatial capabilities SQL geospatial functions have ...

Comment: you can use the df.distance() function to calculate the distance between two points in a GeoDataFrame, but ultimately the scale of the task you are asking for makes it unlikely that it would be a good fit. One thing to look at is this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222315/finding-nearest-point-in-other-geodataframe-using-geopandas

Comment: another option: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.sjoin_nearest.html though I'm unsure how good performance would be..adding it to the answer anyway!